# Do I risk a ban from Nintendo in general if I install software from GitHub?

Tags: nintendo-switch, homebrew

Quote from [Can You Watch Videos From an SD Card on Nintendo Switch?](https://www.alphr.com/nintendo-switch-watch-videos-from-sd-card/)

> There is an unofficial workaround to the lack of a decent media player
> on the Switch. This involves using something called custom firmware
> via the Homebrew App. Be warned. This falls under hacking within
> Nintendo’s terms of Service, and may result in a ban. Being banned by
> Nintendo means that you’ll no longer be able to access the official
> servers and this may affect a lot of online games.
>
> Although this method may work for some versions of Switch, it’s often
> patched out by Nintendo. It also won’t work with the Switch Lite at
> all. This method is unadvisable, as not only may it not work with your
> console, it voids your warranty, and may result in an outright ban.

If I install any software from GitHub on Nintendo Switch, may I no longer be allowed to participate in online games / get a ban?

Is installing [Cpasjuste/pplay](https://github.com/Cpasjuste/pplay) legal in Nintendo terms?

> Installation Switch: copy "pplay" folder to switch sdcard
> ("/switch/pplay")

Excuse the possible stupid question. I'm a fan of GitHub and co, but don't want to risk invalidating my device. Would be very happy if someone explains to me what I can and can not do with installation of software from sources other than the official store.

Comment: I don't think installing software from Github is a problem per se. However, to be able to do that, you probably had to jailbreak your device, which I think is the bigger problem here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running any kind of unofficial software on your Nintendo Switch runs the risk of Nintendo banning your console or account from online services.

In order to run pplay or any other unofficial software on your Nintendo Switch, you first need to jailbreak your Nintendo Switch, which may or may not be possible depending on your Switch's model and firmware. Anyone can upload to GitHub, meaning you shouldn't trust it any more than you would any other file sharing site. In a worst case scenario, custom software can brick your switch making it unusable.

There are various guides on what you can do to avoid getting banned with a jailbroken Switch, but none of these methods are risk free. I've personally jailbroken and overclocked my Switch and haven't been banned, but there is no guarantee of safety.